# MATLAB compiler for LINUX

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am looking to compile a `.m` file (program) from MATLAB to Linux. I have done it on Windows operating system using

```
mcc -mv FILENAME.m
```

I see on the [MATLAB website](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/compilers/R2012a/glnxa64.html) that I can use GNU g++.

Does this work in a similar way to the MATLAB compiler by just writing one line of code in MATLAB or do I have to run it in the Linux terminal?

Also, does this compiler tend to have issues regarding getting the desired output?

Comment: Did you consider using http://www.scilab.org/ ?

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi: true, the MCR is just a headless MATLAB that interprets the code embedded in the deployed application, and runs at the same speed as a regular MATLAB session.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, is called crosscompiling. Here you want from a Windows computer cross compile a Matlab program to a native Linux executable. As of 2009, [this was not possible](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/255455) and most likely isn't now either.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I am not looking to install MATLAB on linux. I am looking to compile a MATLAB program in Linux so that I can run the .exe file from the terminal as this produces output faster.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might try using Octave for Linux.

[Download GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html)